# Ruby/Rails - DateTime parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I'm trying to return a date as a string but remove the first 0 from the hour returned.

This is the code I'm using:

```
t = Time.new

current_date = Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min/30*30)
time_str = current_date.strftime("%I.%M+%p").downcase

puts time_str

Outputs:
03.00+pm

Expected output:
3.00+pm # need to remove the last zero from the hour(s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `%l` instead of `%I`

```
.strftime("%l.%M+%p")
```

Comment: I had to add `strip!` at the end as the returned string was `" 3.00+pm"`. It works, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome buddy.. do not forget to mark it as accepted answer for the help of future visitor.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one point: if you want to quickly find the format string, `man date` will give you the correct answer if you are on OS X or Linux.

If the `strftime` and `date` format string differs, you can always find it up in the Ruby document, here's the [document for `strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime).